# How to pass argument to Start-Process

Tags: powershell, start-process

I'd like to run this command 
`net start "PTV LOXANE xDataServer 1.4.1.067"` using Start-Process in powershell with admin rights.
My problem is how to give the quote to ArgumentList.
I've tried this but it doesn't work

```
Start-Process net -ArgumentList "stop \"PTV LOXANE xDataServer 1.4.1.067\"" -Verb runas -wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru
```

Comment: `"stop \"PTV LOXANE xDataServer 1.4.1.067\""` -> `'stop', '"PTV LOXANE xDataServer 1.4.1.067"'`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Great, now the question has an answer and the poster can't mark it answered.

Comment: @BaconBits Let's be real here, they probably weren't going to accept it anyway. Besides, you're always free to post an answer of your own.

Answer (score 1):

I've found how to do it. You must double the quotes:
`Start-Process net -ArgumentList "start ""PTV LOXANE xDataServer 1.4.1.067""" -wait -PassThru -Verb runas`

Now I've got a second question. How can I run this command when calling powershell ?
This doesn't work:

```
powershell -Command 'Start-Process net -ArgumentList "start ""PTV LOXANE xDataServer 1.4.1.067""" -wait -PassThru -Verb runas'
```